# Image picker library does not work for flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, imagepicker

I am trying to add an image picker package for my flutter app, but it does not work, it also shows that build gradle failed to build.
I have read that it is related to native apps operating system and it must have the latest version and latest versions of grade libraries in order to work,
I have solved the problem using the shortest solutions, I have downgrade the image picker version to ^0.5.4+1
the simulator started but the image cannot be picked from camera, the preview image is not shown.

```
   image picker: ^0.5.4+1

 

     dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }

    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip


W/Binder  ( 7322): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
W/Binder  ( 7322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Binder:7322_2
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:781)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.invokePlatformMessageResponseCallback(FlutterJNI.java:718)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:144)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:231)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerDelegate.finishWithSuccess(ImagePickerDelegate.java:540)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerDelegate.handleImageResult(ImagePickerDelegate.java:505)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerDelegate.access$000(ImagePickerDelegate.java:66)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerDelegate$4.onPathReady(ImagePickerDelegate.java:470)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerDelegate$3$1.onScanCompleted(ImagePickerDelegate.java:160)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at android.media.MediaScannerConnection$ClientProxy.onScanCompleted(MediaScannerConnection.java:204)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at android.media.MediaScannerConnection$1.scanCompleted(MediaScannerConnection.java:53)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at android.media.IMediaScannerListener$Stub.onTransact(IMediaScannerListener.java:61)
W/Binder  ( 7322):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

the code I have written is:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
// import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as syspaths;

class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageInputState createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
  File _storedImage;

  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 600,
    );

    setState(() {
      _storedImage = imageFile;
    });
    // final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
    // final savedImage = await imageFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
    print("_storedImage${_storedImage.path}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            child: _storedImage != null
                ? Image.file(
                    _storedImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  )
                : Text(
                    'No Image Taken',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
        // SizedBox(
        //   width: 10,
        // ),
        Expanded(
          child: FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
            label: Text('Upload'),
            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onPressed: _takePicture,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to update the image picker package to ^0.6.0+10 another error has appeared:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:8: error: package androidx.lifecycle does not exist
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
                         ^
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
  public static Lifecycle getActivityLifecycle(
                ^
  symbol:   class Lifecycle
  location: class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72340

Comment: Thank you, since the feature corresponds to native device and the error is in Android libraries  I have solve it by updating gradle files using distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip and by updating the image picker version to  ^0.6.0+10